# Using Select Layer By Attribute Tool

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am new to ArcPy and was trying to get a new layer from two shapefiles. The new layer would only have the data if the two layers intersect and one of the attributes ("VEGETATION") = "NV".

```
import arcpy
import numpy

#Locations
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\Users\C\Desktop\GIS\Geodatabases"
LClocation = "c:\Users\C\Desktop\GIS\Geodatabases\ex_LandCover.shp"
RBveglocation = "c:\Users\C\Desktop\GIS\Geodatabases\ex_RedBluffVegetation.shp"

a_RBVeg = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(RBveglocation, "VEGETATION")
a_LC = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(LClocation, "LU_CODE")
updateveg = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(a_RBVeg,'INTERSECT', a_LC, 0, 'NEW_SELECTION')

query = '"VEGETETATION" = "NV"'
updatevegQ = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a_RBVeg, "SUBSET_SELECTION", query)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(updatevegQ,'updateveg4')
```

Comment: I would try the Intersect tool followed by the Select (not Select Layer By Attributes) tool.

Answer (score 1):

1

Start by adding a r in front of all paths, for example
`arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\Users\C\Desktop\GIS\Geodatabases"`

([raw strings](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-raw-strings)). Or [some](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) characters might be interpreted as a tab / newline / etc. and the path wont work.

2

When you do

```
a_RBVeg = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(RBveglocation, "VEGETATION")
```

a_RBVeg will be a [result object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm), not the layer. The layer is called `"VEGETATION"` or you can also use `a_RBVeg.getOutput(0)`

So `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(a_RBVeg, ...` wont work.